# How do you set the first row of a Google Sheets Script's DataRange based on a cell value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to use the Google Apps Script sample "Quickstart: Managing Responses for Google Forms" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) to create a sign-up form that also sends Calendar Invites and a personalized confirmation. There's a section that pulls information to create the events in the calendar. I'd like to be able to add events later and have the script create the calendar events, but when I run the script it creates duplicates of the existing events and replaces the existing Calendar Event IDs with the IDs of the new (duplicate events).

All of that said to ask - how do I set the `.getDataRange` to start with the first row that does not have a Calendar Event ID in column F?

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynCIT.png) - I want the DataRange to start with row 3...

I've tried many different things, like IF statements, a failed attempt at making a `rows.filter(function(row)` [which is not a defined function], etc.

```
function setUpConference_() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Conference Setup');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  setUpCalendar_(values, range);
  setUpForm_(ss, values);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
```

EDIT: The calendar event creator section of the script is below. At one point I tried making an IF statement as noted below,

```
/**
 * Creates a Google Calendar with events for each conference session in the
 * spreadsheet, then writes the event IDs to the spreadsheet for future use.
 * @param {Array<string[]>} values Cell values for the spreadsheet range.
 * @param {Range} range A spreadsheet range that contains conference data.
 */

function setUpCalendar_(values, range) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('v7ofe48rps27vdtlkcbcddu0a8@group.calendar.google.com');

/** this was originally   
 * var cal = CalendarApp.createCalendar('Conference Calendar');
 * but I changed it to "getCalendarById" so that it wouldn't create a new calendar every time I ran the script.
 */

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

/** Many versions ago, I tried inserting an IF statement here to see if column F was null, with TRUE continuing the FOR statement and FALSE skipping ahead to the end of this FUNCTION. But, I'm used to VBA and FileMaker (I know, I know), so I don't understand where the "loop" starts, so to speak -- and it didn't work.
*/ 

    var session = values[i];
    var title = session[0];
    var start = joinDateAndTime_(session[1], session[2]);
    var end = joinDateAndTime_(session[1], session[3]);
    var options = {location: session[4], sendInvites: true};
    var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, options)
        .setGuestsCanSeeGuests(false);
    session[5] = event.getId();
  }
  range.setValues(values);

  // Store the ID for the Calendar, which is needed to retrieve events by ID.
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('calId', cal.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
var values = range.getValues().filter(function (r) { return !r[5] })
```

or, with the V8 runtime enabled

```
var values = range.getValues().filter( r => !r[5])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I received this error: "Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 7 but the range has 10." - but if I change [5] to [6] (which I _think_ refers to the column number that I want to be blank - in this case, column F which is the 6th column), the script will run, however it still overwrites the existing Calendar Event IDs and creates duplicate events. I'm happy to share the Google Sheet with you if that would be of assistance.

Comment: Update - I think I was wrong in my previous reply, Column F is actually [5] because Column A is [0]. So back to the original exception error.